# Start activities from message handler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity

I am trying to achieve something like call activities behavior.

I have a MessageHandler that looks like this:

```
public class EventMessagesHandler : Handler
{
        private readonly Context _applicationContext;
        public EventMessagesHandler (Context applicationContext)
        {
            this._applicationContext = applicationContext; // not sure if this is necessary 
        }
        public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            base.HandleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.What == Constants.DISPLAY_OUTGOING_CALL_ACTIVITY)
            {
                Intent outgoingCallIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(OutgoingAudioCallActivity));
                outgoingCallIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(outgoingCallIntent);
            }
            if (msg.What == Constants.DISPLAY_INCOMING_CALL_ACTIVITY)
            {
                Intent incomingCallIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(IncomingCallActivity));
                incomingCallIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(incomingCallIntent);
            }
        }
}
```

And inside my Incoming call activity I have the following code in
`OnClick` button in order to open outgoing call activity:

```
Intent outgoingCallIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(OutgoingAudioCallActivity));
outgoingCallIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
ApplicationContext.StartActivity(outgoingCallIntent);
Finish();
```

The desired behavior is the following:

Lets call incoming call activity - "Activity A" and outgoing call activity - "Activity B".

Here are the requirements:

1. When user clicks decline button - "A" activity should be removed from activity stack and disappear so I won't be able to open it from recent applications.
2. When user clicks answer button - Open activity "B" from activity "A" and remove activity "A" from stack so I won't be able to Go back to activity "A" from "B" and in recent applications I will see activity "B" and not "A".
3. When call is done (either by clicking drop call or remote endpoint dropped call) activity "B" should be finished - meaning it will not be visible in recent applications.
4. When received DISPLAY_OUTGOING_CALL_ACTIVITY message - "B" will be opened without re-initializing it whenever user goes back to activity (either by clicking home button and open it from recent applications or just by opening recent applications and go back to activity)

I believe that most of it can be implemented using ActivityFlags but I have failed to find the right ones to use in order to get the desired result.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: `but I have failed to find the right ones to use in order to get the desired result.`  You can first recheck if you have finished your activity correctly after declining or accepting a call .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the requirements by doing the following:

When starting outgoing activity from handler I had the following activity flags:

```
ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask
```

Opening outgoing activity from incoming call activity had the same flags as above.

Incoming call activity had the following:

```
ActivityFlags.NewTask
```

When I had to close incoming call activity or outgoing call activity I called:

```
FinishAndRemoveTask();
```